# Configure multiple host in apache with ssl on different port

Tags: apache, ssl, virtualhost

Hi i want to run multiple sites on same server with ssl on different ports, here is what i did so far.

**default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.com
    ServerName app.example.com
    DocumentRoot path_to_project_directory
    <Directory path_to_project_directory>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
</Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

With above configuration when i run **https://aap.example.com** on browser it works fine now i want to run same domain on different port with ssl like **https://app.example.com:8000**, so for this i have made another virtual host file like this.

**app.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
    ServerAdmin admin@admin.org
    ServerName app.example.com
    Alias /static/ path_to_project_directory


    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / path_to_project_directory/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess example_wsgi33 processes=3 threads=15 display-name=example_wsgi33 python-path=path_to_project_directory:path_to_project_directory/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages

    <Directory path_to_project_directory>
            WSGIProcessGroup example_wsgi33
            WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
            DirectoryIndex manage.py
            Require all granted
            Options -Indexes -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory path_to_project_directory>
            Require all granted
    </Directory>


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile  /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

but when i try to run **https://app.example.com:8000** it shows me nothing and i'm getting error like took too long to respond..
Anybody has idea how i can run site on different ports.
Here is my **ports.conf**

```
Listen 80
Listen 8000
Listen 8001
Listen 8002

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

**I have already enabled these ports on my digital ocean firewall**

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming, but your first steps in debugging should be to look at Apache logfiles to see if it received the requests and what happened with it.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek there is no logs in apache log files.

Comment: If you mean logs exist but do not show anything for your request, it may mean your request did not reached the webserver so some firewall or routing problem blocked it. Use `tcptraceroute` on the relevant port between client and server to find out where the traffic goes and stops. If you mean instead "there are no logfiles whatsoever" then that is the first problem to solve because logfiles are a useful tool to debug things. But in all cases, your question should be moved to [sf] or another forum, as it is not ontopic here.